# CentOS 7 and Puppet unable to install nc

Tags: puppet, yum, netcat, centos7

I am having a weird issue with having puppet enforce the package nc.

I installed it manually in the end via:   `yum install nc`

I see puppet does it via:
`/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y list nc`
Returns: *Error: No matching Packages to list*

I have tested this by command line as well:
`yum list nc`
Returns *Error: No matching Packages to list*

Yet, when I do:
`yum install nc`
Returns: *Package 2:nmap-ncat-6.40-4.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version*

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a case in this case, to separate versions
one example is using FACT os (which returns the version etc of your system...
the command facter will return the details:

```
root@sytem# facter -p os
{"name"=>"CentOS", "family"=>"RedHat", "release"=>{"major"=>"7", "minor"=>"0", "full"=>"7.0.1406"}}

#we capture release hash
$curr_os = $os['release']

case $curr_os['major'] {
  '7': { .... something }
  *: {something}
}
```

That is an fast example, Might have typos, or not exactly working.
But using system facts you can see what happens.

The OS fact provides you 3 main variables: **name, family, release**... Under **release** you have a **small dictionary** with more information about your os! combining these you can create cases to meet your targets.

Comment: Took me awhile, but I get it now. This is in response to the @Werner comment about @ VassilisAretakis solution only working in some versions of the OS but not in other versions.  So that he could apply different solution based on OS version. OK.

Answer (score 21):

Nc is a link to nmap-ncat.

It would be nice to use nmap-ncat in your puppet, because NC is a virtual name of nmap-ncat.

Puppet cannot understand the links/virtualnames

your puppet should be:

```
package {
  'nmap-ncat':
    ensure => installed;
}
```

Comment: Great, that works for 7, but breaks 6.6:
 Execution of '/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y list nmap-ncat' returned 1: Error: No matching Packages to list

Would I have to update my manifests to split on version, or is there another option?

Comment: [@Werner](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3513601/werner) -- that is what I would do.  And hope that they don't break that feature in the future.  ;)

Answer (score 17):

```
yum install nmap-ncat.x86_64
```

resolved my problem

Comment: yum found the x84_64 version for me without adding that suffix fwiw, so I did `yum install nmap-ncat`